# Change the document root of master domain

Tags: dns, cpanel, document-root

There are so many subdomains and Addon Domains associated to my master domain, all are pointing to the same Document Root (including master domain). Are there any risks or precautions, if I want to change the Document Root of my master domain?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to move the root of your master domain to /public_html/master.com and keep the addon domains at /public_html/addon.com?

I did this at one point, but I had some kind of issue with SSL certificate signing or redirects, I can't remember exactly what it was.

I ended up changing my addon domains so their roots were above /public_html/:

```
/public_html/ - my master root
/addon1.com/ - root for addon domain 1
/addon2.com/ - root for addon domain 2
```

The only downside to this structure is that all of the cpanel system folders are next to my domain folders.

```
.cpanel
.htpasswds
.trash
addon1.com
addon2.com
public_ftp
public_html
```

Comment: Thanks, @oTradeMark. I have already proceeded as the way I wanted and everything went well.